# Android в VirtualBox

Tags: android, linux, virtualbox, виртуальная-машина

Я пытался создать виртуальную машину Android в VirtualBox по [этой статье](https://lumpics.ru/installation-android-on-virtualbox/). Пробовал делать на 64 bit и на 32 bit. На этапе установки все происходило как в статье. Но запускаться она не хочет. Открывается выбор ОС:
[image: Скриншот 1]

дальше она самопроизвольно увеличивает размер окна и я вижу следующее:
[image: Скриншот 2]

Дальше дело не идёт. Я пробовал даже на ночь оставлять. Раньше на этом всё и заканчивалось, но теперь, после очередной попытки, то, что вы видите на второй картинке начало пропадать через несколько секунд, так что на экране остаётся только курсор. Который к тому же ещё и не пишет. Что я изменил - не знаю. Но загружаться не хочет всё равно.

На компе стоит Ubuntu 20.04.

За ответ - заранее спасибо.

Comment: Оперативы сколько выделил? Виртуализация в биосе включена?

Comment: По гайду была более устаревшая версия Android x86, конкретней: 6.0-r3 и 7.1-rc1, а у вас 9.0-r2.

Comment: Да, я попробовал более старую версию адроид и всё заработало. Теперь, впрочем, мне уже это не нужно. Но как запустить новую версию - не понятно.